# How to remove and avoid url directories in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to allow my site to rewrite urls. I have put the following into my .htaccess file in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On

#would be nice to remove member-pages from the URL but no idea how.
#RewriteRule ^members/(.*)/?$ /$1 [NC,R]

#This part works though! 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ ./members/$1/ [L]
```

So far, it takes 
mydomain.com/someUserName or mydomain.com/someUserName/ (with trailing slash) and, if it exists, will load the page at mydomain.com/members/someUserName/ without a hitch. This works like a gem.

What I want now (and am trying to do with the first rewrite rule) is to take a mydomain.com/members/someUserName or mydomain.com/members/someUserName/ and have it show up as mydomain.com/someUserName in the url.

How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, You want to redirect **domain.com/members/foo** to **domain.com/foo** , You can use the following rule for that:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /memebers/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ./members/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It's giving me the error "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." And yes, I want to redirect **domain.com/members/foo** to **domain.com/foo**

Also, you have a typo in the first 'members'; but even fixing that didn't help out.

Comment: I changed the bottom line back to what I had:


    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /member/([^\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]
 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ ./member/$1/ [L]

And it's working! 
    **domain.com/members/foo** goes to **domain.com/foo**,
    **domain.com/members/foo/** goes to **domain.com/foo**,
    **domain.com/foo** goes to **domain.com/foo**,

    BUT **domain.com/foo/** goes to **domain.com/foo/** .

Is there a way to get this to also go to **domain.com/foo**?

Comment: Steven , yes there is way, to fix this you can add a **?** inside the capture group in your last rewrite line ,like this

 ^(.+?)/?$

Comment: I just tried that and didn't have any luck. The slash stays put when i do **domain.com/foo/**